# Copy first character from WCHAR* into LPWCSTR

Tags: c++

I am trying to point an LPWCSTR to just the first letter of a WCHAR* in, but instead it's pointing to the entire string.

```
//my_string points to a string "test"
void GetFirstChar(const WCHAR* my_string)
{
    LPWCSTR str = my_string; // str returns "test", but I want just "t"
}
```

How do I get str to equal just the first character of my_string?

### Update:

I also tried this and str still shows the entire string.

```
//my_string points to a string "test"
void GetFirstChar(const WCHAR* my_string)
{
    LPWCSTR str = &my_string[0]; // str returns "test", but I want just "t"
}
```

Comment: You code is not valid. You should post _real_ code. Do not modify it.

Comment: Oh, it is pointing to the first letter just fine :D the problem must be your usage, where you access values that are different from the one pointed to.

Comment: Even though the code is not valid, why do you feel the need to create an extraneous `LPWCSTR` variable?  Isn't just specifying `a` or `&a[0]` in your code enough?  Second, LPWCSTR is a pointer.  It is pointing to the first character of `a`.  So what exactly is the issue?

Comment: I tried just specifying the first character with &a[0] and str shows the entire string.

Comment: you need to copy the first letter to a new string and then add a \0 after it. so you need a 2 character buffer

Comment: @SkunkSpinner -- Nothing "shows" the entire string.  It just so happens that after the first character, there are more characters.  You are still pointing to the first character, regardless of what the characters after it are.  If you want a C-style string consisting of one character **followed by nothing**, then you have to provide it.  You do that by placing a null terminator after the first character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void GetFirstChar(const WCHAR* my_string)
{
    wchar_t newstr[2];
    newstr[0] = *my_string;
    newstr[1] = 0;
}
```